# How do you stream audio through an iPhone app in the background/killed to the web?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, audio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm wondering what my strategy should be for making a BLE device with a button and microphone that when the button is pressed, streams audio to an iPhone or Android app (even when the app has been killed or is in the background) and streams that audio to an API on the internet?

I should probably also be asking if this is possible? I'm aware BLE probably means extremely crappy audio quality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to create a sort of "intercom" that streams audio on the internet using a smartphone.

The first thing that you need to decide is if the communication between the custom device and the smartphone will be (1) connected or (2) not connected. This depends on your scenario, if the smartphone is usually the same known device (1) or not (2).

In the first case you need to perform a pairing between the two devices, and implement a [GAVDP](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/GAVDP.aspx) profile on the custom device to stream the audio.
In the second case, you need to advertise the stream of data using advertisement packets. However this could be very difficult to achieve since advertisement packets have a very limited payload (31 bytes).

For what concern the background mode, the work is feasible.
Apple has recently added support for BLE [state preservation and restoration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html) to continuously monitor even when your app is no longer running.
In Android, I assume that something similar exists, or in  alternative, you can simply create a service that always run in the background.